# Visual Studio Code not running program

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code is not allowing my program to be run with the Code Runner Extension. I have deleted and reinstalled the application multiple times but that does not seem to help. I have tried deleting and reinstalling JDK and the other extensions that are recommended but to no avail.

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MscLZ.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of each of your system variables.  Please provide this information in such a way that it's clear and easy to read.  A wall of text is not appropriate for this information.  Your error is due to the fact, your java/bin directory, is missing from the system variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code does not know where `javac` lives, since it's directory is not within the `%path%` of your shell. Add `javac` to your `%path%` and it will work.

To do so go to your systems page, click advanced and find the environment variables. Add the folder where `javac` lives to the variable called `Path`. Restart VS Code and you are good to go.